# Deadlock explanation MySQL

Tags: mysql, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I need help solving a deadlock situation I'm facing. Thanks for your help.

I don't understand:

- Why does transaction 2 need an S lock (a gap one, even) on the same
  row for which it already has a X lock (no gap)?
- Why is it holding the lock that    transaction 2 needs? Shouldn't it
  just wait for the record lock    that's blocking it to be released
  and not get any lock meanwhile?

---

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2020-09-14 09:30:07 2b506443a700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3286459055, ACTIVE 2 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 2371545, OS thread handle 0x2b54bdad9700, query id 378353035 admin updating
DELETE FROM `category_item` WHERE `category_item`.`category_id` = 67827
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 1994082 page no 31668 n bits 305 index `PRIMARY` of table `category_item` trx id 3286459055 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 305 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len=4; bufptr=0x2b38e1a51f43; hex= 800108f3; asc     ;;
 1: len=4; bufptr=0x2b38e1a51f47; hex= 80036c8c; asc   l ;;
 2: len=6; bufptr=0x2b38e1a51f4b; hex= 0000c3e36241; asc     bA;;
 3: len=7; bufptr=0x2b38e1a51f51; hex= a20339c012011f; asc   9    ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3286458945, ACTIVE 4 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 3, locked 3
LOCK WAIT 207 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 14575 row lock(s), undo log entries 5900
MySQL thread id 2371540, OS thread handle 0x2b553dd73700, query id 378354050 admin Sending data
INSERT IGNORE INTO category_item_included(category_id, item_id)
              SELECT DISTINCT category_included.category_id, item_id
              FROM category_item JOIN category_included
              ON category_included_id = category_item.category_id
              where category_included.category_id in (44044,44047,44074,44461,67827)
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 1994082 page no 31668 n bits 305 index `PRIMARY` of table `category_item` trx id 3286458945 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 305 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len=4; bufptr=0x2b38e1a51f43; hex= 800108f3; asc     ;;
 1: len=4; bufptr=0x2b38e1a51f47; hex= 80036c8c; asc   l ;;
 2: len=6; bufptr=0x2b38e1a51f4b; hex= 0000c3e36241; asc     bA;;
 3: len=7; bufptr=0x2b38e1a51f51; hex= a20339c012011f; asc   9    ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 1994082 page no 31668 n bits 305 index `PRIMARY` of table `category_item` trx id 3286458945 lock mode S waiting
Record lock, heap no 305 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len=4; bufptr=0x2b38e1a51f43; hex= 800108f3; asc     ;;
 1: len=4; bufptr=0x2b38e1a51f47; hex= 80036c8c; asc   l ;;
 2: len=6; bufptr=0x2b38e1a51f4b; hex= 0000c3e36241; asc     bA;;
 3: len=7; bufptr=0x2b38e1a51f51; hex= a20339c012011f; asc   9    ;;
```

---

THANKS A LOT

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL deadlocks explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63897010/mysql-deadlocks-explanation)

Comment: @akaBase I think the OP separated the first question  into multiple questions (See the comment thread there)

Comment: @akaBase it's as Alon Eitan says